# Style no es igual en todas las paginas

Tags: html, css

Esta es mi primera página web, por lo tanto habrá fallos en la estructura del código. He creado un `button`, le he aplicado CSS en una stylesheet para la posición, pero en ninguna página es la posición del botón igual. 
Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Aquí os dejo el CSS y HTML (lo que falla es el `dropdown-button`, la posición es distinta en estas dos páginas, pero el CSS es el mismo):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>HomePage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Opmaak.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.ico">
</head>

<body>

<h1>WELKOM OP MIJN SITE!</h1>

<div class="nav">
<div class="body">
<hr>
<div class="warning">
 <img src="warning_icon.png" alt="warning icon" style="width:40px;height:40px;border:0px;">
</div>

<i>Deze website is een test voor informatica.</i>

<p style="text-align:left;margin-left:14%;margin-right:5%;">Hey, welkom op mijn site. Dit is een test site, dus het is niet definitief. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.<br>
 Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero,
 sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.
 
    Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
 Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.
</p> 
</div>

<hr>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="aboutme"><a href="aboutme.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a class="games" href="games.html">Games</a></li>
</ul>




<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Multimedia</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="mp4.html">MP4</a>
    <a href="png.html">PNG</a>
    <a href="gif.html">GIF</a>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Opmaak.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>CONTACT</h1>
<div class="nav">

<hr>

<div class="body">
    <p>Hieronder zie je een aantal mogelijkheden van hoe u mij kan bereiken: </p>
    <p>Email : randomname@gmail.com</p>
    <p>Mobiele nummer : +31689675394</p> 
    <p>Twitter : @RandomName</p>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="dancingman">
 <img src="dancingman.gif-c200" alt="dancingman" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:0px;">
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="aboutme"><a href="aboutme.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a class="games" href="games.html">Games</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Multimedia</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="mp4.html">MP4</a>
    <a href="png.html">PNG</a>
    <a href="gif.html">GIF</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

```css
   h1 {text-align:center;background:linear-gradient(to right, gray, black);color:white;position:fixed;top:0px;width:100%;height:7.4%;z-index:1000; margin:0; font-family:font_h1;font-size:33px; }
body {text-align:center;background-color:#fffff;font-size:20px; margin:0;}
a {font-size:30px;}
@font-face {
font-family: font_h1;
src: url(lifestyle.ttf);
}

.warning {position:relative;top:34px;right:200px;}
.nav{margin-left:10%;margin-top:5%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;}
.pikachu{position:relative;right:25px;bottom:38px;}
.dancingman{position:relative;right:27px;bottom:29px;}
.icon_home{font-size:30px;position:relative;bottom:1001px;left:3px;}
.icon_contact{font-size:30px;position:relative;bottom:51px;left:3px;}
.mario {position:relative;bottom:10px;height:400px;width:300px;}
.manmetjas{position:relative;top:10px;height:400px;width:400px;}
.textbody {margin-left:10%;margin-right:4%;text-align:left;}
.textbody2 {margin-left:10%;margin-right:4%;text-align:left;}
.textbodygif {margin-left:18%;margin-right:4%;text-align:left;}
.teamfoto {position:relative;top:50px;}
.games {position:fixed;top:203px;width:13.2%;}
.aboutme {position:fixed;top:250px;width:15.6%;}
.pingpong {position:relative;height:170px;width:200px;right:206px;top: 60px;}
.mariobros {position:relative;height:170px;width:200px;right:196px;top: 100px;}
iframe {
position:relative;
top:40px;
padding-bottom:50px;

}
a.game:link {color:blue; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none;font-size:25px;}
a.game:visited{color:blue; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none;font-size:25px;}
a.game:hover{color:red; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:underline;font-size:25px;}
p.pingpong2{position:relative;bottom:100px;left:415px;text-align:left; width:500px; margin-top:20px; }
p.mario2{position:relative;bottom:60px;left:423px;text-align:left; width:500px; margin-top:20px;}
span.titlegame1 {position:relative; bottom:88px; right: 187px;font-size: 25px;}
span.titlegame2 {position:relative; bottom:48px; right: 170px;font-size: 25px;}
hr {opacity:0.6; margin-left:5.3%;}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 15.6%;
background-color: #e0e0e0;
position: fixed;
height: 600px;
overflow: auto;
right:1129px;
top:47px;
border:1px solid #939496;
left:0px;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: #000;
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:30px;

}


button:hover{
 background-color: #4dd6e2;
color: white;
}


li a.active {
background-color: #309ba5;
color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #4dd6e2;
color: white;
}


.dropbtn {
background: #e0e0e0 url('dropdown_icon.png') no-repeat 0;
background-size: 25px 25px;
background-position:96% 65%;
color: black;
padding: 16px 25px;
font-size: 30px;
border: none;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Times New Roman;
position:fixed;
left: 1px;
top:148px;
width: 210px;
height: 55px;
z-index:0;
}


.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
width: 90px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
bottom:20px;
right:439px;
}


.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}


.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #4dd6e2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En ambas páginas, si le aplicas el `CSS`, el resultado es el mismo. El botón se muestra en la misma posición. Puedes comprobarlo aquí:

[Ejemplo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/khn82dkj/2/).

[Ejemplo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/khn82dkj/3/).

Por lo tanto, estoy prácticamente seguro de que tu problema reside en que no estás enlazando bien el CSS con tus páginas. Al estar usando rutas relativas, tienes que estar seguro de que las estás indicando correctamente.

Por ejemplo, al indicar `href="Opmaak.css"`, tu página de CSS tiene que estar en la misma carpeta en la que se encuentra el html. En caso de que estuviera en otra ruta distinta, tendrías que poner esta ruta en relación a tu archivo CSS.

Por ejemplo, tomando como referencia la siguiente estructura:

```
|
|---vistas
|      |
|      |--- vista1.html
|      |--- vista2.html
|
|---CSS
|      |
|      |--- Opmaak.css
```

Tu ruta tendría que ser `../CSS/Opmaak.css`.

Comment: lo siento, se me olvido decir que era problema del dropdrown-content, el dropdown-button si que funciona. Aqui el ejemplo: https://gyazo.com/795014e8f01343594798d085c18f84cd

Comment: @JuanVan12 ¿Puedes añadir el código para ese dropdown-content? Como puedes ver en los links que te he indicado la página no se ve igual.

Comment: Tendria que funcionar, ese es todo el código para el dropdown

Comment: @JuanVan12 Es que en el video que has proporcionado en el comentario no se ve igual tu menú como en los enlaces que has proporcionado. ¿Estás usando alguna librería externa?

Comment: Lo he editado, he metido todo el CSS.

Comment: @JuanVan12 Yo también he editado los links. Como puedes observar en los dos se ve en el mismo sitio. ¿O lo que quieres es ponerlos en un lugar distinto?

Comment: Si observas el video, los botones estan en el mismo sitio, pero el dropdown-content (teniendo el mismo CSS), no. No se si sera un problema del margin de algun objeto o algo parecido.

Comment: @JuanVan12 Sí, me he dado cuenta después de que en los dos links que te he pasado debí de copiar el html dos veces y por eso salen iguales. Ahora ya he visto que fallaba. Luego le echo un vistazo más a fondo.